# Find document in MongoDB collection based on time condition and write timestamp back?

Tags: python, mongodb, time, pymongo

I have a DB with "accounts" collection like this:

```
{u'timestamp': u'2016-06-09 23:29:50.083093', u'account': u'admin:password', u'_id': ObjectId('5766932f6f340ca9a70cdb16'), u'is_valid': u'True'}
```

I need to select one document based on this condition: if is_valid is true and if timestamp has passed 24 hours. So it should be **True** and current time **2016-06-10 23:29:50.083093** to pass the condition. Then I have to update timestamp of this document with current time.

How can I achieve this? I know how to apply the first condition:

```
import pymongo 
from datetime import datetime

try:
  conn=pymongo.MongoClient()
  db = conn.instagram
  collection = db.accounts
  res = collection.find_one({"is_valid": "True"})
  print res
except pymongo.errors.ConnectionFailure, e:
  print "Could not connect to MongoDB: %s" % e
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`$lt` operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/lt/) with a `datetime` instance passed as an argument:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

dt = datetime.now() - timedelta(hours=24)
res = collection.find_one({"is_valid": "True", "timestamp": {"$lt": dt}})
```

Comment: Added "str" `{"$lt": str(dt)}})` and it works, thanks!